# Scrolling with two UICollectionViews

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit, scrollview

I have two collectionviews in my ViewController. The first one scrolls horizontally and the second scrolls vertically. The horizontal collectionview is at the top of the screen and the vertical scrolling one is right underneath it.

This is similar to how instagram has its stories on top of the instagram feed.

I used this scrollView function to offset the collectionviews when I scroll but the background of the top collectionview still stays on screen. Can anyone assist me with also having the background move when the bottom collectionview scrolls.

Here is my scrollView code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if feedCollectionView == scrollView {
            var scrollBounds = storiesCollectionView.bounds
            scrollBounds.origin.y = feedCollectionView.contentOffset.y
            storiesCollectionView.bounds = scrollBounds
        }
    }
```

Here is a gif of how it looks right now:

[image]

I am looking to have similar functionality as the instagram app when you scroll through the home feed.

Comment: Look into `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` -- this may walk you right through what you're going for (not mine): https://nemecek.be/blog/72/building-instagram-profile-screen-with-compositional-layout

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use one collection with two different layouts for each section

Comment: Thank you!! I didnt think about looking into that. I was only debating between two collectionviews or nesting them inside a tableview. Have a good day!